# How do I use the old XmlSerializer with Web API, instead of the DataContractXmlSerializer?

Tags: c, .net, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API site that has, up until now, supported only JSON.

I'm trying to get it to work with XML, and I've run into issues.

There are a couple of things about the DataContract XmlSerializer that bug me. First, it imposes an order on the XML elements, and managing the namespaces is a mess.

It was suggested that I configure my site to use the older XmlSerializer. The code to enable this is supposed to be simple, just set the UseXmlSerializer flag on the XmlFormatter:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    ...
}

public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;

        ...
    }
}
```

And it doesn't work.

If I do not set UseXmlSerializer = true:

- If I submit a request with "Accept: application/json", I get JSON
- If I submit a request with "Accept: application/xml", I get XML

If I do set *UseXmlSerializer = true*:

- If I submit a request with "Accept: application/json", I get JSON
- If I submit a request with "Accept: application/xml", **I get JSON**

Which makes no sense at all.

Something that may be related - we're using Swagger to create API documentation pages:

If I do not set UseXmlSerializer = true:

- The Swagger IO Response Content Type dropdown includes "application/xml"

If I do set *UseXmlSerializer = true*:

- The Swagger IO Response Content Type dropdown does not include "application/xml"

Seeing that, I tried explicitly adding support for xml in WebApiConfig.Register:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.UseXmlSerializer = true;
    config.Formatters.XmlFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/xml"));
    ...
}
```

This makes no difference. The Swagger UI still does not include the xml media types, and requests that ask for XML still return JSON.

Comment: Why would you concern yourself with the order of the XML elements?

Comment: I don't.

It's an optional thing, in XML, but MS has decided that their DataContractSerializer is going to impose an order, and it's a pain-in-the-ass.